# use command prompt to delete an HKCU registry on a remote PC?

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I want to delete an HCKU registry on a remote PC. On a local PC, the command is the following:

reg delete "hkcu\printers\connections" /f

However, how can I do this to a remote PC?  The command help for reg delete says only HKLM and HKU (not HKCU) are available on remote machines.

I'm working in XP/Win7

Thanks,
G.

Answer (score 3):

You need to find user's [SID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier) first. For that you can use `wmic` or any other way you want:

```
wmic /node:<computer-name> useraccount get name,sid
```

Then you just run

```
reg delete "\\<computer-name>\HKU\<SID>\printers\connections" /f
```

Comment: This only works if the user's registry hive is **loaded**, and it cannot be done using `reg load` over the network (but might be possible using `regedit` or other tools, or using `reg load` over SSH, or over PowerShell Remoting).

Comment: When I enter the command "wmic /node:W2-IS-2R04MS1 gbcrondock get name,sid"  I get "Invalid Global Switch" - I'll try enclosing the PC name in quotes...

Comment: Ultimately, I want to remotely delete the PC's printer connections, not just the user's printer connections.  So, perhaps there's another way to do this aside from deleting the hkcu thingy.